# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id by Solr in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, solr, connector

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using MongoDB & Solr 4.6.0.

i found in some articles MongoDB-Solr connectivity is possible with Mongo-Connector...

For this in my system i installed Mongo-Connector successfully

when i run the following command its giving the following errors

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8080/solr -d Desktop/mongo-connector/mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py
```

in terminal its giving the following logs

```
2014-04-22 12:19:35,572 - INFO - Beginning Mongo Connector
2014-04-22 12:19:35,619 - INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
2014-04-22 12:19:35,660 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/luke?show=schema&wt=json' (get) with body '' in 0.049 seconds.
2014-04-22 12:19:35,670 - INFO - MongoConnector: Empty oplog progress file.
2014-04-22 12:19:35,674 - INFO - OplogThread: Initializing oplog thread
2014-04-22 12:19:35,676 - INFO - MongoConnector: Starting connection thread MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
2014-04-22 12:19:35,682 - INFO - OplogThread: dumping collection mydb.testData
2014-04-22 12:19:35,684 - INFO - OplogThread: dumping collection test.testData
2014-04-22 12:19:35,724 - INFO - OplogThread: dumping collection Naresh.products
2014-04-22 12:19:35,726 - INFO - OplogThread: dumping collection mine.products
2014-04-22 12:19:35,727 - INFO - OplogThread: dumping collection mine.mine
2014-04-22 12:19:35,788 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8080/solr/update/?commit=false' (post) with body 'u'<add><do' in 0.054 seconds.
2014-04-22 12:19:35,790 - ERROR - [Reason: None]
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">38</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id</str><int name="code">400</int></lst></response>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector-1.2_-py2.7.egg/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 439, in dump_collection
    dm.bulk_upsert(docs_to_dump())
  File "Desktop/mongo-connector/mongo_connector/doc_managers/solr_doc_manager.py", line 185, in bulk_upsert
    "Could not bulk-insert documents into Solr")
OperationFailed: Could not bulk-insert documents into Solr
2014-04-22 12:19:35,792 - ERROR - OplogThread: Failed during dump collection cannot recover! Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'local'), u'oplog.rs')
2014-04-22 12:19:36,678 - ERROR - MongoConnector: OplogThread <OplogThread(Thread-2, started 140192603404032)> unexpectedly stopped! Shutting down
2014-04-22 12:19:36,678 - INFO - MongoConnector: Stopping all OplogThreads
```

And in Solr Server logs its giving the following error

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
    at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getIndexedId(AddUpdateCommand.java:92)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:582)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:435)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:174)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:710)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:953)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1014)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I know this is because of the unique field **id** But already i defined that field as unique.

Here is my **Schema.xml**

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Still also its giving the same error why ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: did you actually provided id field in the document that you added? moreover what is the content of `2014-04-22 12:19:35,788 - INFO - Finished 'http://localhost:8080/solr/update/?commit=false' (post) with body 'u'<add><do' in 0.054 seconds.` this row?

Comment: @ymonad  Thanks for the fast reply... I'm not getting can you please explain little bit more.

Comment: sorry, this message is raised because you don't have id field in the document you want to add. e.g. `<add><doc><field name="id">...</field></doc></add>`, not in Schema.xml but in message posted by mongo connector.

Comment: i think its for Solr reindex.. i'm not sure about that i'm new to this

Comment: oh.. thanks @ymonad i'll add that field in my doc & i'll check it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I got it.
MongoDB uses `_id` as unique id. Therefore you should change

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

to

```
<field name="_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<uniqueKey>_id</uniqueKey>
```

or supply `--unique-key=id` option to mongo-connector.

see https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-Solr

Comment: actually i tried with both fields...  i added <uniqueKey>_id</uniqueKey> and <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

Comment: There's also an example `schema.xml` file that already has these fields defined. You could modify that file to get started: https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/blob/master/mongo_connector/doc_managers/schema.xml